# Number of FS or SF instances in a binomial process

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ be the rv counting the number of instances where we are geeting a failure followed by success or vice versa in a binomial experiment with n trials and p=1/2,How can we find the distribution of X?I will b obliged for any help

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Getting the mean isn't hard...getting the variance is more work, but not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Write success as $+1$ and failure as $-1$. Then the $n-1$ random variables given by the products of two successive trials are mutually independent ($\rightarrow$ exercise). Thus the number of pairs with different outcomes has binomial distribution $\mathsf{Bin}\left(n-1,\frac12\right)$. (Note that this doesn’t work for $p\ne\frac12$ because the products aren’t independent in that case.)

Comment: This is so elegant.Thank you for this wonderful answer

Comment: +1 after the edit - I was typing the same $2p(1-p)$

Comment: @Henry: Yes, I'd meant to write $\frac12$ but wrote $p$ instead (which happens to be the same in this case), and when I noticed the mistake I figured I might as well show where the $\frac12$ comes from...

Comment: Though I am starting to worry that they are not independent if $p \not=\frac12$.  If one step has no change, then I think that  the next step has conditional probability $\frac{p-p^2}{1-2p+2p^2}$ of changing, while if the first step has a change then the next step has conditional probability $\frac12$ of changing

Comment: @Henry: Yes, again we had the same thought process – I just corrected the answer in that regard :-)